# Picture library filter by enterprise keyword

Tags: search, metadata, tags, enterprise

I've set up a SharePoint picture library to share within my company.
I've added "enterprise keywords" to the pictures in order to find them in the total overview of all pictures.

this all works quite well, though I'm struggling with filtering by the keywords. It works for a single keyword, but if I select more keywords to narrow the search results, I actually get more results.

for instance, I've selected the UK, so I get pictures from the UK, if I then only want to see pictures taken in 2018 I would include 2018 in the filter options. instead of getting pictures taken in 2018 in the UK I get **ALL** pictures taken in the UK **AND** all pictures taken in 2018 (so including France, Netherlands, etc.)

Is there a solution in SharePoint that can actually narrow down the searchresults with more searchterms?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not in SharePoint-standard, no. Multi-Selecting will always be an `or` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Enterprise keywords that consider all terms as equal, you should have used managed metadata columns and use as refiner/filter the Managed Metadata navigation (see section Key Filters in the image below)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/813689
This way you could have searched UK AND 2018 instead of UK OR 2018.